# Машинное обучение для новичков

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Недавно начал заниматься машинным обучением в плане изучения ее теории и необходимых математических знаний. Хотелось бы теперь начать практиковаться, но вот не знаю, что можно пытаться самому написать... Не мог бы кто-нибудь подсказать примеры какие нейросети можно пробовать реализовывать, начиная с самого низкого уровня и увеличивая его по мере прогресса?

Comment: Зайдите на kaggle.com

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал реализовывать те сети, которые описаны в учебниках, которые вы выбрали. А к   kaggle  и пр. переходить, накопив уже хотя-бы такой опыт.  Иначе в голове точно будет каша. Да и выбрать ни метод решения ни подходящую задачу без соответствующего набора знаний вы не сумеете. А в учебниках обычно все уже продумано и предусмотрено за вас.